# Applicability of Same Origin Policy (SOP) when IP address is remapped via NAT

Tags: ip, same-origin-policy, nat

When an inbound/outbound TCP/IP traffic is faced with NAT address mapping, it's perfectly possible to have a different IP address as your request origin every few minutes. This is how most of the commonplace web application receives the client's IP address information.

If NAT addressing toggles the broadcast IP addresses, would this suppose to affect the Same Origin Policy where host IP address, port no. etc is monitored tightly to determine the origin?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy  <--- where does IP come in?

Answer (score 1):

Same Origin Policy is applied based on the domain name in the URL, i.e. how the server is called from the perspective of the browser. This name does not change if you use NAT. And even if you have an IP address instead of a hostname in the URL the address as seen from the browser would still be the same.